# iPhone SE 2016 Activation Lock

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, homebrew, activation-lock

My friend's mother recently passed away and she gave me her Mom's old iPhone SE to wipe. I did this. However, neither of us know the Apple ID password and we were not able to turn off Find My on the phone. Now it is activation locked and I don't know what to do.

I tried following a tutorial for Darkra1n to remove it, but it said I needed Palera1n first. I downloaded Palera1n and ran it, but it keeps getting stuck at "Booting PongoOS". I have tried downloading from Github, from Homebrew, and from the site. I have even tried it on both Apple Silicon and Intel. What should I do? Are there other tools I can use? Not paid, if possible, please. I tried using Blackra1n iCloud Lock removal. but the palera1n mod didn't work (gaster_Darwin.zip could not be found).

Please help!

Comment: Does that mean no? I can't do it?

Comment: There is no bypassing the activation lock without Apple's assistance.

Comment: Hi all! We ended up signing in on iCloud and resetting everything -- password and security questions. I then removed the phone from her iCloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to contact Apple in order to have the activation lock removed. If your friend can provide you with proof of purchase, that should be enough for Apple to ascertain that you are now the legimate owner of the phone - and they can remove the activation lock.